# IntelliJ - Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm getting this weird issue when trying to import an SBT project into IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE.

The message is simply `Unable to load AWS Credentials from any provider in the chain`.

I've tried exposing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as environment variables for my session, and I know for sure that the values that I'm setting is correct. I've also tried creating a `~/.aws/credentials` file, but neither of these are doing anything towards fixing this error. I think this is specifically an IntelliJ error, because I can run this project in my console using `sbt` just fine.

Here's a snippet from my `sbt.last.log`. It's not super helpful.

```
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.ow2#ow2;1.3 {}:
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.ow2.asm#asm-parent;4.1 {}:
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.ow2#ow2;1.3 {}:
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.ow2#ow2;1.3 {}:
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.ow2#ow2;1.3 {}:
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error]     Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
[error] Total time: 596 s, completed Apr 5, 2016 10:59:14 AM
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Update: I updated to IntelliJ 2016 CE, and am still having this same problem.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I was able to get it working was using the `~/.aws/credential` file (I'm using the latest IntelliJ CE).

Inside your `~/.aws/credential` add:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id={NO_QUOTES_KEY}
aws_secret_access_key={NO_QUOTES_SECRET_KEY}
```

The profile name inside `[]` has to be **default**. It did not work with any other profile name.

Comment: It used to work for me, but not without any clear reason, it doesn't work anymore. :(

Comment: Does bootstrapping sbt really require AWS Credentials?!

Comment: This worked for me, I think it only works with the default profile

Answer (score 3):

I ended up just running

```
sbt compile
```

or (Activator which is a superset of SBT)

```
activator compile
```

from the command line, which resolved (and downloaded) all the dependencies, then opened it up in IntelliJ.

Hope that works for you too.